# Android Intent "goings and comings" between two activity (on two different app) problem passing data

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two apps that need to communicate with each other and at each call send data to the other one
Each of these applications must be "persistent" and they need to be created only one time.

The problem is that after my first startActivity I manage to switch from one application to another, but the data I put via putExtra is null.
And I really don’t understand why. I made a ton of log and what I read make no sens for me

If you have a tutorial, or sample who work for what I want to do, this would be very appreciable.
I am sure that I make a lot of mistake thank for your time and help

```
package com.example.app2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String Key = "key";
    String TAG = "----- MainAct : ";
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app2", "com.example.app2.TestActivity1"));
        Log.d(TAG, "in onCreate");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
package com.example.app2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity1 extends Activity {
    String Key = "Key";
    String TAG = "----- Act 1 : ";
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Log.d(TAG, "in onCreate");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intentOnClick = new Intent();
                intentOnClick.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app2","com.example.app2.TestActivity2"));
                intentOnClick.putExtra(Key, editText.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG+"Value intentOnClick : ", editText.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intentOnClick);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Log.d(TAG, "in onResume");
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            if (intent.getStringExtra(Key) != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "What is in the view : "+intent.getStringExtra(Key));
                textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Key));
            }
        }
    }
}
package com.example.app2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity2 extends Activity {
    String Key = "Key";
    String TAG = "----- Act 2 : ";
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Log.d(TAG, "in onCreate");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intentOnClick = new Intent();
                intentOnClick.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app2","com.example.app2.TestActivity1"));
                intentOnClick.putExtra(Key, editText.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG+"Value intentOnClick : ", editText.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intentOnClick);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Log.d(TAG, "in onResume");
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            if (intent.getStringExtra(Key) != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "What is in the view : "+intent.getStringExtra(Key));
                textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Key));
            }
        }
    }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app2">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App2">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".TestActivity1"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".TestActivity2"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thank for youre help

EDIT here my log (for some reason I need to post it in "code format")
Here my logs, I don't understand why it work for one and not the other... Why the TextField change for one and not the other ... Why the intent.getextra(key) doesn't work more than one time...

```
Launch app 
MainAct :: in onCreate
Act 1 :: in onCreate
 Act 1 :: in onResume

First time in Activity1 : (TextField = Default / TextView = Default) 
I set/write "Value from act 1" in the TextField and clic
Act 1 : Value intentOnClick :: Value
Act 2 :: on Create
Act 2 :: on Resume
Act 2 :: What is in the view : Value

First time in Activity2  (TextField = Default / TextView = Value from act 1):
I set/write "Value from act2" in the TextField
Act 2 : Value intentOnClick :: Value
Act 1 :: in onResume

Second time in activity1 (TextField = Default / TextView = Value from act 1) :
I set/write "NewValue from act1" in the TextField
Act 1 : Value intentOnClick :: NewValue from act 1
Act 2 :: in onResume
Act 2 :: What is in the view : Value from act 1

Second time in Activity2 (TextField = Value from act2 / TextView = Value from act 1) :
I set/write "NewValue from act1" in the TextField
Act 2 : Value intentOnClick :: NewValue from act2
 1 :: in onResume

Third time in Activity1 (TextField = Default / TextView = NewValue from act 1) :
I set/write "NewNewValue from act1" in the TextField
Act 1 : Value intentOnClick :: NewNewValue from act 1
Act 2 :: What is in the view : Value from act 1
Act 2 :: in onResume

Third time in Activity2 (TextField = NewValue from act2  / TextView = Value from act 1) :
[...]
```